# How to change connection sting of entity data model while moving application to stage?

Tags: entity-framework-4

I am an application with an EDMX file. My connection to this edmx is different in stage from the development environment. i wanted to change the connection string of edmx file while moving application to stage environment.

I tried removing the edmx and creating a new edmx with the stage environment. edmx is getting created fine. But the edmx entity class is not getting referred in the code i.e it's not even showing in the intellisence.

Is there a way to change the connection string directly instead of deleting and adding edmx?
If yes, please post that how we can achieve.

Thanks,
venugopal